# Is it possible to search SQLite database that has base64-encoded some text strings?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, base64

I know you can query a dataBase like so

```
 NSString *strSelectQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE songname LIKE '%%%@%%'", str];
```

However, the problem is I encoded the strings (base64) before storing the data into my sqlite database. So regular searches from search bar won't work in this situation. I have another solution that grabs all the Data and stores it in an array then I can predicate it. However, I am wondering if there is a way to search data using the query above somehow even when the strings are encoded by base64.

Comment: I used base64 decode to shortened the string. The strings can be very long.

Comment: @Rob I apologize, I got my terminology completely wrong here. I haven't been completely awake today. I encoded huge strings using base 64 before putting in my sql database. In other words, the strings in my database are base64 encoded and not base64 decoded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130307/discussion-between-rob-and-weakman10122).

Comment: The previous developer did this and I believe (not 100% sure) has to do with all the syntax errors since it all JSON data. I removed the encoding and I get syntax issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [chat with you](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130307/discussion-between-rob-and-weakman10122), it became clear that the previous developer was having trouble inserting values into the database, so he chose to base64-encode those strings.

Bottom line, searching for substring within base64 string is technically possible, but surprisingly complicated and highly inefficient. I would not advise attempting to doing so.

Instead I would not base64-encode the strings in the database at all. The database will be smaller (base64-encoded string is 33% larger than original payload), the code will be simpler, and searching will now work without any effort at all.

---

You mentioned that you encountered errors when trying to insert text values into your database. This is because using `stringWithFormat` to build SQL can cause problems. Consider:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO book (title) VALUES ('%@')", title];
BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:sql];   // FMDB method
```

But that would fail if the title contained an apostrophe:

> Finnegan's Wake

Yes, base64-encoding could get around that problem, but, better, you could just replace that with SQL with `?` placeholders, too:

```
NSString *sql = @"INSERT INTO book (title) VALUES (?)";
BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:sql, title];
```

---

By the way, to search, you'd also want to use `?` placeholders:

```
NSString *sql = @"SELECT * FROM book WHERE title LIKE ?";
NSString *searchTerm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%", searchString];
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:sql, searchTerm];
```